# WPF Checkbox Combobox clicar direto em botão após seleção

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Tenho algumas comboxboxes as quais preencho com checkboxes. Após selecionar os itens clico em pesquisar, porém o primeiro clique é utilizado para comprimir a combo e então clico novamente para acionar o botão.

Há alguma maneira de evitar ter que dar 2 cliques para acionar um botão após a abertura de uma combobox? Fazer com que o primeiro clique comprima a combo e acione o botão.

Como é: clico na combobox, seleciono os itens, clico fora da combo, clico no botão. (obs. mesmo clicando sobre o botão, o primeiro clique sempre é para comprimir a combo).

Como seria: clico na combobox, seleciono os itens, clico no botão.

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Column="3" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="cmbGrupo" 
    IsEditable="True"
    IsReadOnly="False"                     
    Width="120" 
    SelectedIndex="0" 
    >
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
                x:Name="chkGrupo" 
                Content="{Binding Content}" 
                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" 
                Checked="chk_Changed" 
                Unchecked="chk_Changed"
                />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>

<Button 
    x:Name="btnPesquisar" 
    Content="Pesquisar" 
    Grid.Column="17"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Width="130" 
    Click="btnPesquisar_Click"
    />
```

Comment: Sem código fica difícil te ajudar. Acrescente o código do combobox e do botão.

Comment: Feito @StanleyIPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, o que acontece é que o ComboBox foi implementado de maneira que quando o DropDown está aberto ele captura o mouse. Isso é nativo do ComboBox e significa que:

Da [Capturar e Uncapture o mouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms771301.aspx?sentenceGuid=15ce18327f7fc5bee89e296a41672cc3#mt2):

> Quando um objeto capturar o mouse, todos sistema autônomo eventos relacionados de mouse são tratados sistema autônomo se o objeto com a capturar do mouse executar o evento, mesmo se o ponteiro do mouse estiver sobre outro objeto.

Então é esse o motivo do seu problema.

Agora sobre:

> Há alguma maneira de evitar ter que dar 2 cliques para acionar um botão após a abertura de uma combobox? Fazer com que o primeiro clique comprima a combo e acione o botão.

Até onde eu sei, existe duas maneiras e várias variações delas. Vou colocar as duas maneiras.

Primeiro método:

```
   private void Win_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmbGrupo.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
        Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler(cmbGrupo, OutsideControlClick);
    }

    public void OutsideControlClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        cmbGrupo.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

- Ao carregar a janela ele adicionará o evento "AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCaptured" para o seu ComboBox. Isso significa que um evento é executando quando algum botão do mouse é pressionado fora do elemento que está capturando eventos do mouse ([referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedownoutsidecapturedelement(v=vs.110).aspx)).
- O evento só é ativado quando clicar dentro da `Window`. Os botões "Fechar" e "Minimizar" do `Window`, não ativarão o evento.

Segundo Método:

```
private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point m = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, this.FilterCallback, this.ResultCallback, new PointHitTestParameters(m));
    }

    private HitTestFilterBehavior FilterCallback(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        Control control = obj as Control;
        if(control == null) return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        if(control is Window) return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        if(control is ComboBox) return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop; 

        if (control.Focusable)
        {
            MouseDevice mouseDevice = Mouse.PrimaryDevice;
            MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs = new MouseButtonEventArgs(mouseDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
            {
                RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
                Source = control
            };
            control.RaiseEvent(mouseButtonEventArgs);
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
        }
        return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
    }

    private HitTestResultBehavior ResultCallback(HitTestResult r)
    {
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
```

- Ao fechar o `DropDonw` ele focará o controle onde o ponteiro está posicionado antes de executar outra ação com o mouse.

No seu caso eu colocaria algum desses métodos em uma `DepedencyProperty` para reaproveitamento. Caso faça isso, compartilha aí conosco ;D

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços

Comment: Utilizei a primeira opção, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!